# How to Display CSV file content in Controller as an Array?

Tags: php, csv, zend-framework2

I am trying to display CSV data to array or something as an output using Zend Framework 2

I have created "hello world" module and the controller calls works fine.

> **CSV File location is data/csv/Foo.csv**

Below is my controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{
  $filename = 'data/csv/Foo.csv';
  $useFirstRecordAsHeader = true;
  $delimiter = ',';
  $enclosure = '"';
  $escape = '\\';
  $this->file = new SplFileObject($filename);
  $this->file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV | SplFileObject::READ_AHEAD | SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY | SplFileObject::DROP_NEW_LINE);

  $this->file->setCsvControl($delimiter, $enclosure, $escape);

  $this->useFirstRecordAsHeader = $useFirstRecordAsHeader;

   return $this;
    
}
```

But right now I am getting the error:

> SplFileObject::__construct(csv/Foo.csv): failed to open stream: No
> such file or directory

My CSV file is in the same folder `controller/csv/Foo.csv`

How to read a CSV file content and display as output array or any other format? I want to do it using Zend Framework 2 only.

Comment: Please try to keep csv/Foo.csv inside public folder and try again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to open `$this->file = new SplFileObject('csv/Foo.csv');`, since you are using a relative path, on execution time that wont resolve to the folder where your controller is at (it will probably resolve to `[yourprojectroot]/csv/Foo.csv`).

If you **really** wanted to store this csv in `controller/csv`, you should use something like:

```
 $this->file = new SplFileObject(dirname(__FILE__) . '/csv/Foo.csv');
```

But, saving that csv there is bad for a several reasons. First you'd need to grant write permission to your webserver to be able to write in that directory, and you'd be fundamentally messing up with your data/code structure (data and code shouldn't reside together, but in easily separated silos).

Better, create a folder "data" and and another folder "csv" in your projects directory, give your webserver permission to write there ([`chmod` || `chown`, other methods](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174114/99888)), and do something like:

```
 $file = 'data'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'csv' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Foo.csv' ;
 $this->file = new SplFileObject($file );
```

Besides that, I'm not sure what you are returning actually makes sense. Try something like:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $filename = 'data' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'csv' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Foo.csv';;
    $this->file = new SplFileObject($filename);
    $this->file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV | SplFileObject::READ_AHEAD | SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY | SplFileObject::DROP_NEW_LINE);

    $this->file->setCsvControl(',', '""', '\\');
    $this->useFirstRecordAsHeader = true;

    $response = $this->getResponse();
    $headers  = $response->getHeaders();
    $headers->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'text/csv');

    $contents = $this->file->fread($this->file->getSize());

    $response->setContent($contents);
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , i have puted csv file in data directory now i guess its open but thing is i am getting blank output. not getting data . I have updated the question with updated code please help me ?

Comment: What i need to print to get csv file data ?

Comment: This will output the CSV as is... the "output as array" is kinda weird. What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: no worries i get the output what i want , just last question where to define this DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ? as you have mention in controller but exactly where it define ?

Comment: You don't have to define DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. Is already defined. http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php

Answer (score 3):

You should not put your `csv` directory in the `Controller` directory, as it is not a controller. It's against the MVC architecture. The good practise is to put data in the `data` directory, under your root directory, at the same level as your `module` directory.

So assuming you have it on this `data` directory, you can simply write:

```
$this->file = new SplFileObject('data/csv/Foo.csv');
```

or better (for portability):

```
$filename = 'data'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'csv' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Foo.csv' ;
$this->file = new SplFileObject($filename );
```